# What is the name for this meta magic-trick?

Tags: puzzle-identification, cards, magic

In his book *Intuition Pumps and Other Tools for Thinking* Daniel Dennett describes a system of layering magic tricks in the following way:

> There are some effects—they can hardly be called tricks—that might work only once in a thousand times! Here is what you do: You start by telling the audience you are going to perform a trick, and without telling them what trick you are doing, you go for the one-in-a-thousand effect. It almost never works, of course, so you glide seamlessly into a second try—for an effect that works about one time in a hundred, perhaps—and when it too fails (as it almost always will), you slide gracefully into effect number 3, which works only about one time in ten, so you’d better be ready with effect number 4, which works half the time (let’s say). If all else fails (and by this time, usually one of the earlier safety nets will have kept you out of this worst case), you have a failsafe effect, which won’t impress the crowd very much but at least it’s a surefire trick. In the course of a whole performance, you will be very unlucky indeed if you always have to rely on your final safety net, and whenever you achieve one of the higher-flying effects, the audience will be stupefied. “Impossible! How on earth could you have known which was my card?

What is the name for this system of composing magic tricks together?

**Explanation in response to comments**: I should say that I'm not at all familiar with magic, but when I read this passage my thoughts went to something like a card guessing trick where prior to appearing on stage, you place a card chosen at random under one of the seats in the audience. Then later, when performing some trick in which the aim is to guess a card chosen by a volunteer in the audience, IF that card happens to be the same one you previously concealed, then you can replace your surefire trick (which I assume would be impressive in its own right) with the much more spectacular trick of making the chosen card appear to be in possession of an unsuspecting audience of the member.

Repeating this process with results of increasingly lower probability (guessing two cards, three cards, four cards at a time, etc) would give you a sequence of increasingly more impressive results ordered in exponentially decreasing order of likelihood.

The beauty of something like this is that you get a spectacular result essentially with very little work, the only downside, of course, being its unpredictability.

Comment: Do you know that it actually has a name? I don't know whether this is even a thing that stage magicians do: it's not obviously worth it since usually its only effect is to complicate the performance of that final surefire trick, and if your surefire tricks "won't impress the crowd very much" then you need better surefire tricks.

Comment: The "surefire trick" has been rehearsed so many times that there is almost zero chance of it failing, yet its result *looks like* an impossibility: zero chance of succeeding. So why would a stage magician play the odds and almost always end up with a weak trick? They don't rely on luck, but endless practice, and perhaps this scheme comes from a lazy magician. One artist who did make layering work was the late [Tommy Cooper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tommy_Cooper) who developed a style of bodging his tricks and then pulling off something unexpected.

Comment: This doesn't seem to me to be related to puzzles at all - am I missing something?

Comment: @WeatherVane I wonder if perhaps this is something that was made up by the author of the book in order to illustrate some other point, rather than an actual technique used by real magicians.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a puzzle, nor a question about puzzles. While a magic trick can be seen as a puzzle when you try to work out how it is done, this question is not about that either.

Comment: One term for the various alternative things you might have to do is "multiple outs".